# How i can get information of authorized user in BjyAuthorize in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I have BjyAuthorize in my Zend Framework 2 application.

How i can get information of authorized user in onBootstrap function of Application Module?

Also i use ZfcUser and ZfcAdmin.

I need to show authorized user's login or email on site pages.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear; do need to find the *authenticated* user or are you testing the users' *authorization*?

Comment: I need to show authorized user's login on site page.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can save to the database all loged inn users, and then reset the bit when they logg out.

A better way is to save the timestamp of the last activity to every user, and then list all users that have accessed the application the last 10min...